# Not able to search google results from Python

Tags: python, compiler-errors, google-search

I am working on a project that speaks out google search results. Everything is working fine accept this piece of code.

Code

```
from googlesearch.googlesearch import GoogleSearch
response = GoogleSearch().search("something")
for result in response.results:
    print("Title: " + result.title)
    print("Content: " + result.getText())
```

Error Recieved

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Programming/Python/Projects/Smart-Actions/gSearch.py", line 3, in <module>
    from googlesearch.googlesearch import GoogleSearch
  File "C:\Users\vinay\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googlesearch\googlesearch.py", line 6, in <module>
    import urllib2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'
```

I am running `Python 3.7.6` , Please help me in resolving this error.

Comment: Have you tried installing the missing package `urllib2`? Did you install `googlesearch` using `conda` or in some other way?

Comment: urllib2 is for python2 so your code works for python2 since it is using python2 module.

Comment: You can edit the code of  `googlesearch.py`. Just remove urllib2 and import urllib instead. You have to modify a lot to make it work for python 3.